# Krugman Model: Profit Maximization (relation price elasticity of demand and elasticity of substitution)

Tags: elasticity, elasticity-of-substitution

the pictures outline the situation and my problem. The only thing I dont understand, is why the inverse of the price elasticity is equal to the negative elasticity of substitution? (price elasticity is equal to negative elasticity of substitution?). I realize that there is a hint in the footnote, on how to derive this, but I failed.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: Ding Dong, Notes on Krugman (1991)

This is how I think this should be done, but something is missing or im doing something wrong... :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your Lagrangian has a $p_i$ in the first term that shouldn't be there.